# getting errors while using the sfml library in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory, sfml

```
   #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
   #include <SFML/Window.hpp>
   #include <SFML/System.hpp>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <stack>
   using namespace sf;
   using namespace std;

class picture;
vector<picture*> picStack;

class picture
{
public:
    Image *mainImage;
    unsigned long long fitness = 0;
    picture(Vector2u size){
        mainImage = new Image;
        mainImage->create(size.x, size.y);
    }

    void test(Image objective){
        for (int i = 0; i < mainImage->getSize().x; i++)
        {
            for (int o = 0; o < mainImage->getSize().y; o++)
            {
                fitness += abs(mainImage->getPixel(i, o).r - objective.getPixel(i, o).r);
                fitness += abs(mainImage->getPixel(i, o).g - objective.getPixel(i, o).g);
                fitness += abs(mainImage->getPixel(i, o).b - objective.getPixel(i, o).b);
            }
        }
    }

    void generate(){
        for (int i = 0; i < mainImage->getSize().x; i++)
        {
            for (int o = 0; o < mainImage->getSize().y; o++)
            {
                mainImage->setPixel(i, o, Color(rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255));
            }
        }
    }

    void draw(Vector2f position, RenderWindow *window){
        Texture texture;
        Sprite sprite;
        sprite.setPosition(position);
        texture.loadFromImage(*mainImage);
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        window->draw(sprite);
    }

    ~picture(){
        delete mainImage;
    }
};

void reproduce(picture *male, picture *female){
    picStack.push_back(new picture(female->mainImage->getSize()));
}
```

This is an oversimplified version of the code where I got the error, it itself originates from the "void reproduce()" function above. I added the "picture" class just for context, try to ignore its effects on the code lenght; I am not asking you to debug my program. I cant find the cause of the error despite extensive research. I am using SFML version 2.2 and running the code in visual studio 13.

here are the errors I got:

```
First-chance exception at 0x59CA7921 (sfml-graphics-d-2.dll) in sfml.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.
Unhandled exception at 0x59CA7921 (sfml-graphics-d-2.dll) in sfml.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.
```

Comment: Seems like a null pointer. Not sure though, I'd need to know the rest of the code to say for sure. EDIT: You sure that both female and female->mainImage are set properly (are not nullptr)?

Comment: I ran some tests and it seems like they are not null pointers, however the mainImage seems to have no size related to it, hence why I get errors when I try to access it. The pointer itself does not seem to be null.